# Multiple git users

Tags: git, version-control, pull-requests

On GitHub if I want to contribute to another user's repo I clone it, make changes and submit a PR, at which point the owner can choose to merge or not. I am trying to figure out how to create a similar flow with a private Git server.

We have a Git repo at work that I do 90% of the work on, but occasionally my co-worker will make changes and for whatever reason he refuses to tell me when he does, which results in frustrating conflicts and lost time.

As far as I can tell from Googling, there can only be one user listed in git-config.. am I understanding this point correctly? How can I achieve a workflow as described in the first paragraph?

Comment: What is your issue? Is it with the workflow for your coworker or is it with configuring the git server?

Comment: @marstato the former, I was trying to solve with the latter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be only one user listed in the local git config. Correct. But this does not mean that you cannot have multiple repository owners. 
When you create a project in GitHub, GitLab or any other git repository, you can have multiple collaborators and also different roles for the project collaborators.

So for example, if you are loosing a lot of time to resolve the conflits and merge the code of your co-worker, then you can give him the rights so that he can also do this job.

For me personally, the best way is not to Clone a project, but rather, to force all the collaborators to Fork the project. In this way, they will first have to commit and merge the changes to their own Master first, before making a merge request to the Project Master. This flow is safer, and easier to control.

Either way, is a matter communication and you guys as a team need to talk and decide the best way to organize your flow of development.

I also recommend you to take a look at Gitflow, which is a great tool to collaborate as a team using Git.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Comment: Gitflow is fairly complicated; that complexity is probably only justified for *large* software projects and teams.

Comment: Another thing, as Christophe mentioned above, every user can have his/her own user in his/her local config. Don't mistake Git for GitHub. 
Here you can find the more about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321556/difference-between-git-and-github

Comment: thanks.. what i'm taking away from this is that i need to give him his own user on the OS first.. currently there's just one user account on that server called "git." thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Both you and your coworker are using a single machine with a single account to do all development work ?

Comment: @Occam'sRazor you should probably go ahead and set yourself up with a legit login while you’re at it.

Comment: @TurtleKwitty not developing on the git server obviously. its sort of a miscellaneous server that has side projects and long running processes on it. I just created a user for git because some tutorial told me to.. the repos arent even in the git users home directory they're in /repos..

Comment: @RubberDuck I have one. some tutorial lead me to believe git worked best with it's own user. sounds pretty stupid in retrospect..

Comment: Not stupid @Occam'sRazor. A dedicated service user makes a lot of sense if you’re running a [git server for public consumption](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol). I suspect you were reading [this man page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) when what you really wanted was to set up Git ssh access, which is really no different from simply setting up plain ol’ ssh access for a user.

Comment: @RubberDuck if you arent on the same machine to do the work then what is stopping you from setting up your own machine to do the work and then push to the central repo ?

Comment: @TurtleKwitty the docs I linked to are for setting up a central repo.